# C++ Qt editor question

Tags: c++, qt, persistent

I have the case when I have to manually close the persistent editor for the `QTableWidget`.

By default, closing the editor this doesn't result in saving the changes to the `QTableWidgetItem` (it simply discards them).

**I wish to save these changes along with the `closePersistentEditor` call - how should it be done?**

*I tried emitting `cellChanged` before the `closePersistentEditor` call - it didn't help*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you can write something like this

```
void MyTableWidget::commitAndClosePersistentEditor(const QTableWidgetItem* item)
{
    if (!item)
        return;

    QModelIndex index = indexFromItem(item);
    QWidget* editor = indexWidget(index);
    commitData(editor);
    closePresistentEditor(item);
}
```